# dropdown menu with wp_nav_menu and foundation won't show

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make a menu with **top bar** (foundation) and **wp_nav_menu**. I've done it before and it was working perfectly but this time I need it to be a **dropdown menu**.

The problem is it show the sub-menu/dropdown-element below my menu as if it was a totally different menu. How can I resolve this?

My code

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#" ><span></span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
    <?php
      wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => "Top Menu" ) ); 
    ?>
    </ul>

    <ul class="right" id="social-media">
      <li><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'search-1' ); ?></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a> Social Media 1 </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a> Social Media 2 </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a> Social Media 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </section>        
</nav>
```

Also it won't show the menu-icon when I have a small/mobile screen. It won't change to dropdown mode at all in this resolution.

**EDIT :**

I figure out how to show only my dropdown menu. I simply use *walker* and set up my menu like this :

```
Parent 1
  Child 1-1
  Child 1-2
  Child 1-3
Parent 2
  Child 2-1
  Child 2-2
  Child 2-3
```

But I still have a problem with my menu-item. My Menu-Icon won't hide in medium and up and my parent won't hide in small.

New wp_nav_menu :

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location' => 'main',
  'menu' => 'Top Menu',
  'container' => false,
  'depth' => 0,
  'items_wrap' => '<ul class="left">%3$s</ul>',
  'walker' => new reverie_walker( array(
    'in_top_bar' => true,
    'item_type' => 'li',
    'menu_type' => 'main-menu'
  ) )
) );
```

CSS :

```
#navigation-menu {
    background-color: $primary-color;
    h2 {
        display: none;
    }
    nav {
        li{ 
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }   
    .top-bar-section {
        .left{
            li {
                float: none;
            }
        }
        .divider {
            width: 0%;
        }
        .dropdown:hover {
            background-color: $white !important;
            color: $primary-color !important;
        }
        .dropdown {
            .parent-link {
                display: none;
            }
            :active {
                background-color: $white !important;
                color: $primary-color !important;
            }
        }
        #social-media-top {
            margin-right: rem-calc(10);
            margin-left: rem-calc(-30);
            padding-left: rem-calc(0);      
            li {
                margin-right: rem-calc(-15);
            }
            #searchform {
                margin-top: rem-calc(-5);
                margin-bottom: rem-calc(5);
                #searchvalue {
                    display: inline;
                    margin-left: rem-calc(-40);
                    opacity: 0.6;
                }
                #searchsubmit {
                    margin-bottom: rem-calc(-15);
                    width: rem-calc(25);
                    height: rem-calc(40);
                }               
            }
            .social-top {
                width: rem-calc(60);
                height: rem-calc(45);
                img {
                    opacity: 0.6;
                }
                :hover {
                    opacity: 1; 
                    background-color: $primary-color !important;                
                }               
            }
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: there is a html markup error in the first ul. it should be <li class=".."> instead of <class="...">

Comment: my bad I forgot to my <li> here but I check and I have it in my code. I figure out how to solve the first problem but I still have my second problem which is my menu-icon. I'll edit my question.

Comment: The problem with the menu-icon is very likely a css issue, so a demo or at least some css code would be of value

Comment: I update my post with the css I use for my top bar section but I don't see any problem in it. Like I said I use a top bar in my others websites and I only have problem with this one.